# apache2 config: enable access to /server-status while having catch-all 301 redirects

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I have an Apache2 server with various virtual servers running. For SEO purposes, anything that does not match www.mydomain.com is automatically redirected to www.mydomain.com.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com$1 [R=301,L]
```

This is working fine but I want to monitor status of the apache server by calling http://localhost/server-status?auto

The problem is that this is redirecting to http://www.mydomain.com/server-status which is not a valid URL. What additional redirect can I add to avoid this problem?  Or is there some other way this can be tackled?

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/server-status
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But this didn't help me. The issue was a bit of complication with DocumentRoot pointing to /var/www/mydomain, access rights for /server-status location (Allow from 127.0.0.1 instead of Allow from localhost) and then adding a special virtual host for localhost.